# How can I msg to skype?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, skype, msg

How can it send a msg to someone written in the application, I have the java down below but this one asks me to write the name that I skype msg to

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.skypemsg)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    String skypeName = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_skypeusername)).getText().toString().trim();
    if(skypeName.length()<=0)
    {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter skype username to message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
     String mySkypeUri = "skype:"+skypeName+"?chat";
     SkypeUri(MainActivity.this, mySkypeUri);
    }
   }
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. If you don't want to ask for the name, where do you want to get it from?

Comment: If I run the application; it would ask me to out a username and then it takes me to Skype to send the msg, what I want is to go to Skype where the username is already written in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your comment, I think you want to do this (fill in the correct name):

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.skypemsg)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
     String skypeName = "yourSkypeName"; // <-- change this
     String mySkypeUri = "skype:"+skypeName+"?chat";
     SkypeUri(MainActivity.this, mySkypeUri);
   }
  });
```